# Azure blob storage container directory max size

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, blobs

I need to upload images in Azure blob container, and every image should be saved in her own directory in container. I want to save different sizes of the same image and take it when i need. Can i set up max size of the directory of every image in the container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can i set up max size of the directory of every image in the container?

Except to the default [Azure Storage Limits](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-docs/blob/master/includes/azure-storage-limits.md), Azure Storage Service doesn't provide any way to limit the max size of a blob item which in a directory. I suggest you control the limit in your application when you upload file to Azure Storage.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Yes, i think that i will control the limit in the application.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. If my reply is helpful for you, please mark it as answer.